# Replace every other occurence on the same line

Tags: sed

To get pair coordinates, I need to bundle them with a comma.

Example input (space divided)

```
161768.669 467646.462 161716.059 467515.711 161683.343 467434.35 161696.535 467427.091 161713.457 467416.235 
161719.332 467412.183 161732.58 467403.047 161763.757 467381.118 161791.136 467367.094 161808.447 467361.612 161834.383 467353.808 
161842.354 467351.71 161870.358 467344.337 
161886.521 467338.28 161905.239 467330.484 161908.865 467328.974 161972.72 467301.688 161984.372 467296.404 162000.0 467288.568 162056.152 467260.414 
162065.771 467254.859 162102.992 467233.363 162138.102 467213.086
162146.165 467209.29 162165.68 467200.102 162165.684 467200.1 162270.285 467154.666 162318.855 467133.104 162358.101 467117.844 162165.004 466820.119 162176.208 466809.875
```

This attempt only replaces the first occurrence on every line
`sed 's/ /,/1' file`

```
161768.669,467646.462 161716.059 467515.711 161683.343 467434.35 161696.535 467427.091 161713.457 467416.235
161719.332,467412.183 161732.58 467403.047 161763.757 467381.118 161791.136 467367.094 161808.447 467361.612 161834.383 467353.808
161842.354,467351.71 161870.358 467344.337
161886.521,467338.28 161905.239 467330.484 161908.865 467328.974 161972.72 467301.688 161984.372 467296.404 162000.0 467288.568 162056.152 467260.414
162065.771,467254.859 162102.992 467233.363 162138.102 467213.086
162146.165,467209.29 162165.68 467200.102 162165.684 467200.1 162270.285 467154.666 162318.855 467133.104 162358.101 467117.844 162165.004 466820.119 162176.208 466809.875
```

Desired output

```
161768.669,467646.462 161716.059,467515.711 161683.343,467434.35 161696.535,467427.091 161713.457,467416.235
161719.332,467412.183 161732.58,467403.047 161763.757,467381.118 161791.136,467367.094 161808.447,467361.612 161834.383,467353.808
161842.354,467351.71 161870.358,467344.337
161886.521,467338.28 161905.239,467330.484 161908.865,467328.974 161972.72,467301.688 161984.372,467296.404 162000.0,467288.568 162056.152,467260.414
162065.771,467254.859 162102.992,467233.363 162138.102,467213.086
162146.165,467209.29 162165.68,467200.102 162165.684,467200.1 162270.285,467154.666 162318.855,467133.104 162358.101,467117.844 162165.004,466820.119 162176.208,466809.875
```

Can this be done with sed or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a number followed by a space and a number to be replaced with a number followed by a comma and a number, for all occurences (the flag `g`).

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\) \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\)/\1,\2/g'
```

You might want to change how exactly a "number" is defined but this should work as long as you have digits before *and* after the decimal point, and you always have a decimal point.

If you don't care at all about whether these are number at all, you could do it even simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for `awk`, because allows you to loop through fields quite easily:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s,%s%s", $i, $(i+1), (i==NF-1?"\n":" ")' file
```

#### Explanation

The idea is to loop through fields in blocks of two. Hence:

- `for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2)` normal loop with a seed of 2. (Is it correct to call it "seed"? Just guessing)
- `printf "%s,%s%s", $i, $(i+1), (i==NF-1?"\n":" ")` prints two fields separated by comma. It adds a space or new line, depending on the loop position.

This would also work:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s,%s ", $i, $(i+1); print ""}'
```

#### Test

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "%s,%s ", $i, $(i+1); print ""}' file
161768.669,467646.462 161716.059,467515.711 161683.343,467434.35 161696.535,467427.091 161713.457,467416.235 
161719.332,467412.183 161732.58,467403.047 161763.757,467381.118 161791.136,467367.094 161808.447,467361.612 161834.383,467353.808 
161842.354,467351.71 161870.358,467344.337 
161886.521,467338.28 161905.239,467330.484 161908.865,467328.974 161972.72,467301.688 161984.372,467296.404 162000.0,467288.568 162056.152,467260.414 
162065.771,467254.859 162102.992,467233.363 162138.102,467213.086 
162146.165,467209.29 162165.68,467200.102 162165.684,467200.1 162270.285,467154.666 162318.855,467133.104 162358.101,467117.844 162165.004,466820.119 162176.208,466809.875
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll keep the solution, but for now I go for sed.

Answer (score 0):

A ruby one-liner:

```
ruby -ane 'puts $F.each_slice(2).map {|*pair| pair.join ","}.join " "' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# posix version (non GNU sed or use --posix)
sed 's/\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \([^ ]\{1,\}\)/\1,\2/g' YourFile

GNU sed version
sed 's/\([^ ]+\) \([^ ]+\)/\1,\2/g' YourFile
```

Replace any space between a peer of non blank group by a comma. it doesn not replace space between 2 peer because sed start the next substitution AFTER the last one so next non blank group is no including the following space